# custom svg filter not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, svg, svg-filters

This below code works fine in chrome and filter is applied but fails in firefox. An extra space is also added by direct inclusion of svg definition in the html(This is present in all browsers). Not sure why its happening like this. Can someone let me know the issue, I am new to **svg**

Here is the codepen link: http://codepen.io/susheel61/pen/wJYgwr

```
<svg version="1.1" id="ThemeSvg">
    <defs>
        <g>
            <!--/* Polygon definitions for overlay shape */-->
            <rect id="red-poly" x="0%" y="0%" width="53%" height="100%" fill="#b5121b" transform="skewX(-10)"></rect>
            <rect id="rect-fade-out" x="0%" y="0%" width="53%" height="100%" fill="url(#fade-out)" transform="skewX(-10)"></rect>
        </g>
        <g>
            <filter id="red-angled-overlay" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">
                <!--/* Bring in the mask for fading the image out */-->
                <feImage xlink:href="#rect-fade-out" result="red-overlay" x="0" y="0"></feImage>
                <!--/* Create composite of image and fade mask */-->
                <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="red-overlay" operator="out" result="composite"></feComposite>
                <!--/* Bring in the colored polygon for the overlay */-->
                <feImage xlink:href="#red-poly" result="overlay" x="0" y="0"></feImage>
                <!--/* Blend the overlay with the faded image */-->
                <feBlend in="composite" in2="overlay" mode="multiply"></feBlend>
            </filter>
        </g>
    </defs>
</svg>

<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 840 474" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMin slice">
    <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://wowslider.com/sliders/demo-10/data/images/autumn_leaves.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" filter="url(#red-angled-overlay)" class="svg-black-overlay"></image>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Firefox does not support [feImage filters where the image is a fragment](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=455986). It only supports feImage where the image is a complete standalone image or a data URI of a complete SVG document.

You'd have to create two additional standalone SVG images one with each polygon definition in and point the feImage elements at the complete image document in each case.

Comment: Can you add an example I am a not clear what you are mentioning as I am new to SVG

Comment: Create a complete svg document, stick the rect in it. Point the filter to the document rather than the rect.

Comment: What if i have multiple rects in same file and i want to refer one of the rect.?

Comment: Firefox would not support that, you'd need multiple files.